# page/2 not working in wordpress it showing 404 page erorr

Tags: pagination

I created a custom template page for the custom post. The name of the custom post page is: `single-college_directory.php`and the custom post page template name is `collage-directory.php`. I added pagination code to the template page, It show's the navigation but while I click the `2` Page, It goes to 404 Page.

The code of the template page is given below.

```
        <?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' =>1,
        'post_type'=>college_directory,
        'paged' => $paged
        );
        $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while($custom_query->have_posts()) :
        $custom_query->the_post();  ?>

                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <div><?php   the_post_thumbnail( array(65, 65))?></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                <p class="media-p"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

On the above code I did't added the pagination code. But, while access the page 2 and other pages, It show's 404 page error instead of showing the post listing.

I didn't edited anything in Htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem solved. The problem with My wordpress has the following.

> I created both **CUSTOM POST NAME** and **PAGE** name as same.

Solution for the problem is:

> Change **PAGE** or **CUSTOM POST TYPE** Name. It must be different not be same.

Now I can access `page/2` or `page/3` without getting any 404 page error.